# How to convert a list of lists into a unique Pandas DataFrame column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

For a list as:

```
L = [[0,1,1,0],
     [0,1,1,1],
     [1,0,0,1],
     [1,1,0,0],
    ]
```

And I want to make a `DataFrame` as:

```
      Column Name
0       [0,1,1,0]
1       [0,1,1,1]
2       [1,0,0,1]
3       [1,1,0,0]
```

The reason is that each individually list is an object by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a direct solution:

```
import pandas as pd

L = [[0,1,1,0],
     [0,1,1,1],
     [1,0,0,1],
     [1,1,0,0],
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame([[L[i]] for i in range(len(L))], columns=['Column Name'])

# output
# Column Name
# [0, 1, 1, 0] 
# [0, 1, 1, 1] 
# [1, 0, 0, 1] 
# [1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the list as a indexed `dictionary` formed by the list of values:

```
import pandas as pd

L = [[0,1,1,0],
     [0,1,1,1],
     [1,0,0,1],
     [1,1,0,0],
    ]

Df = pd.DataFrame({i:[vals] for i,vals in enumerate(L)},index=['Column Name']).T
```

It will returns:

```
    Column Name                                                                                                                                        
0  [0, 1, 1, 0]                                                                                                                                        
1  [0, 1, 1, 1]                                                                                                                                        
2  [1, 0, 0, 1]                                                                                                                                        
3  [1, 1, 0, 0]
```